# What is the difference between running a from cmd line vs. double click?

Tags: cmd.exe, mouse-click, exec

I have a miner program and if i double click and run it, it works fine, but if i run it from the cmd line using executable name it doesnt run, it crashes.

I tried to run with `CreateProcess` function using `DETACHED_PROCESS`, still if the calling executable is called from cmd it fail. What is the difference between them ? Could it be something about startup info ? Can I trigger like a double click from cmd if that is possible somehow ?

Comment: I would run it each way while running Process Monitor and see if you can spot anything of interest when you compare the two.  The stacks of the process create events will detail the difference in the way process is created.

Comment: Have you try `start "" /b /d "c:\Program Files\Miner\Folder\” "minerProgram.exe”` in command line?